# In NHibernate, how to find the name of the id property of a persistent POCO class knowing its type?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How can I obtain the name of the id (primary key) property for my entity class using NHibernate class metadata? Suppose I have the following class, can I find the property name and type for ID of `typeof(TEntity)`?

```
public abstract class Repository<TKey, TEntity> : IRepository<TKey, TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private static string PrimaryKeyName;
    // ...

    protected ISession Session { ... }
}
```

Usually, the name of the property is `Id`, but in few cases, it differs. I am using `.hbm.xml` mappings. Does

```
Session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(TEntity)).IdentifierPropertyName
```

provide this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes

```
Session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(TEntity)).IdentifierPropertyName
```

is the property name of the identifier.

There is also `IdentifierType`, which is the NHs `IType` of the identifier. You can use `SetIdentifier` and `GetIdentifier` to read and write values to and from the identifier.